# drawRectangle error on highcharts-more.js[dynamic] file

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am having issue with `highcharts-more.js` file . It started giving me error below ;

```
CRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'drawRectangle' of undefined or null  reference 
highcharts-more.js, line 41 character 24
```

in dynamic highcharts-more.js file I am seeing error at this stage :

```
g.polygon=v(g.scatter,{type:"polygon",fillGraph:!0,getSegmentPath:function(a){return t.prototype.getSegmentPath.call(this,a).concat("z")},drawGraph:t.prototype.drawGraph,drawLegendSymbol:k.LegendSymbolMixin.drawRectangle});
```

I don't have this piece of code in current js file but it appears only you debug the application

and I don't see any `drawRectangle` inside js file but when I debug it , I see it in dynamic js file

It wasn't like that before until I installing vs2013 .

I am using this jsfiddle code in my code and same data . But it works here on jsfiddle

[jsfiddle here!](http://jsfiddle.net/za4y9aaq/5/)

Any idea why I am having this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: And in what circumstances do you get this error?

Comment: drawRectangle is highchart's built-in function.... The problem is not with this function.... Some object is trying to use this function where the object itself null

Comment: and  This happens when our configuration that is chart creation parameters could have been not sufficient to generate the chart

Comment: but I can't catch the error on the current js files. so I can't fix it

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The error is not occuring on your JSFiddle. It's hard to fix if you can't reproduce it.

Comment: Maybe you are using different versions of the Highcharts? Use latest version in your dev and production env.

Comment: I just updated them to latest version but still same error

Comment: The issue is resolved  .  I was using CDN for highcharts-more.js file but then I changed the src to js/highcharts-more.js  and it worked.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved . I was using CDN for highcharts-more.js file but then I changed the src to js/highcharts-more.js and it worked